# web2py CURD.search() and permissions

Tags: python, database, crud, relationship, web2py

I've this function for search

```
@auth.requires_login()
def find_template():
    form, rows=crud.search(db.templates,query=db.templates.active==True)
    return dict(form=form, rows=rows)
```

it works fine, but the user is able to find his templates and the other templates of other users! (but he can't edit them as i fixed this already)

so i put this

```
@auth.requires_login()
def find_template():
    form, rows=crud.search(db.templates,query=[db.templates.active==True,
                                               db.templates.user_id==auth.user_id])
    return dict(form=form, rows=rows)
```

now the user can find nothing, it shows `NONE` or `No Data`

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` argument has to be in proper DAL query format, not a list of conditions. Try:

```
query=((db.templates.active==True) & (db.templates.user_id==auth.user_id))
```